# Bitcoin QT restore old wallet.dat - needed for Israel supreme court

Tags: wallet-recovery

Though I am sure it's probably not the first time you get this inquiry,
I am pretty sure it has some unique characteristics.

My name is Roy Arav. I am from Israel. In Israel, banks totally forbid getting/sending money that is related to crypto. So in 2018 I sued the bank in Israel's highest court. In February 2021, I won. (For those of you that know Hebrew, it was published in Israeli newspapers and [the verdict was published online](https://www.psakdin.co.il/Court/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%97-%D7%A0-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%A7-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9C-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9E#.YKiirqhvY2w).)

Well, the bank appealed this verdict to Israel's supreme court. Winning or losing, it's going to be compelling precedence for all similar cases from now on.

### Why am I telling you all this?

I need to prove that there is no money laundering (there isn't) by showing
the route of the money (how I bought it, what transactions I did, and how I sold it back to shekels). One of the nodes in this route is an old bitcoin-qt wallet I had till 2019. It's empty now, but I can't access the wallet to see the transactions or even to see some public addresses.

I have my password and an old wallet.dat (I am not sure it's the most up to date one), and I am trying now to re-sync the whole thing (it's going to take at least a week). Any advice? (I don't mind publishing the wallet.dat and password since the wallet should be empty.)

Comment: Bitcoin Core (bitcoin-qt) has maintained backwards compatibility. You should be able to open the wallet with a modern installation of Bitcoin Core and be able to see all of the transaction history.

Answer (score 1):

Being that you have the wallet.dat file (and the password), one option that you may want to consider is using pywallet to dump the private keys and public addresses from the wallet.dat file.  See https://medium.com/crypto-blog/how-to-recover-old-crypto-wallet-private-keys-with-pywallet-bafdaeb4928e for more info.